# Create mysql view replacing a set of ints with corresponding strings

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql view where I store a set of values (hard,average,easy) as ints(3,2,1). Is there any way to create a mysql view (for my own analytics) that would replace the ints with their corresponding values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you storing the values?  I mean, if you just "know" that these are the values, then use `case` or `elt()`:

```
select t.*, elt(val, 'easy', 'average', 'hard') as string_val
from t;
```

`elt()` happens to work because the values are sequential starting at 1.  Otherwise, `case` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CASE`:

```
select case col
        when 1
            then 'easy'
        when 2
            then 'average'
        when 3
            then 'hard'
        end
from t
```